# Salvar o conteúdo do editor Quill "wysiwyg"

Tags: html, post, wysiwyg, editor

Estou construindo uma página de de postagem estou com uma dificuldade na implementação na hora de pegar o conteúdo.

- Quill
- Editor

Desde já grato pela ajuda!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<!--Função que manda o conteúdo da div para a textarea com o clique do botão-->
<script>
    $(() => {
        $('#saveDelta').click(() => {
            var valorDaDiv = $("#editor")
            $("#post").val(valorDaDiv)
        })
    })
</script>
<!--div que contem o valor a ser repassa a textarea-->
<div id="editor" class="texteditor"><b>Digite o texto aqui!</b></div> <br>
<!-- form que com o botão que pega o conteúdo da div atualiza a textarea e salva no banco -->
<form action="/admin/novo_post" id="post" method="POST">
    <textarea name="post" id="post" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="saveDelta">Salvar</button>
</form>
<!--Quando retiro o form atualiza a textarea mas não salva no banco com o form o conteúdo da div não vem e salva a textarea no banco em branco-->
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está utilizando o mesmo `id="post"` tanto no form quanto no textarea. Troque o id do form por `id="form"`, e o `type` do botão por `button`.

Pegue o HTML do editor com `$(".ql-editor").html()`. A classe `.ql-editor` refere-se à div editável criada pelo plugin. Use um `setTimeout` para dar um curto atraso antes de submeter o form, para antes adicionar o HTML do editor no textarea.

Vai ficar assim o HTML:

```
<form action="/admin/novo_post" id="form" method="POST">
    <textarea name="post" id="post" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="saveDelta">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

E o JS:

```
$(() => {
   $("#saveDelta").click(function(){
      var valorDaDiv = $(".ql-editor").html();
      $("#post").val(valorDaDiv);
      setTimeout(()=>{
         $("#form").submit();
      }, 50);
   });
});
```

Comment: como eu poderia estar recuperando imagens passado por esse editor Quill ?

Comment: vc quer pegar o caminho das imagens?

Comment: na verdade gravar no servidor. como faz esse cara aqui http://codepen.io/jackmu95/pen/EgBKZr, conforme essa issue: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1089 . Porém pra mim não dispara o evento imageHandler

Comment: Vc precisa subir a imagem pra algum servidor. No exemplo que vc passou, me parece que ele usa uma API que envia a imagem para um servidor. Não sei como funciona isso.